# Ruby on rails openssl error when creating new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm a newbie to Ruby and I've been going through the lynda.com ruby on rails essential program.

I'm using windows7 with ruby 2.0 and with rails 3.2.12

However when creating a ruby project I get this error.

```
         run  bundle install
E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:917:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 e
rrno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL
::SSL::SSLError)
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:917:in `block in connect'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:51:in `timeout'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:917:in `connect'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:861:in `do_start'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:856:in `start'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendo
r/net/http/persistent.rb:628:in `start'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendo
r/net/http/persistent.rb:570:in `connection_for'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendo
r/net/http/persistent.rb:930:in `request'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/fetch
er.rb:195:in `fetch'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/fetch
er.rb:169:in `use_api'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/sourc
e/rubygems.rb:223:in `block in remote_specs'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/sourc
e/rubygems.rb:223:in `select'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/sourc
e/rubygems.rb:223:in `remote_specs'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/sourc
e/rubygems.rb:162:in `fetch_specs'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/sourc
e/rubygems.rb:66:in `specs'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in index'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:189:in `each'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:189:in `block in index'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/index
.rb:9:in `build'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:185:in `index'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:179:in `resolve'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:114:in `specs'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/insta
ller.rb:83:in `run'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/insta
ller.rb:14:in `install'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/cli.r
b:247:in `install'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendo
r/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendo
r/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendo
r/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendo
r/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/bin/bundle:20:in
`block in <main>'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/frien
dly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.0/bin/bundle:20:in
`<main>'
        Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
        troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
```

Can anyone help me out here. I want to learn rails but I don't know what this is or what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Gemfile generated by Rails, you see that is connecting to rubygems via SSL.

`source 'https://rubygems.org'`

Simply change this line to

`source 'http://rubygems.org'`

This is not a great idea in the long term or for a deployment system, but it can get you up and running while the issue is sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

This Error discribed here: http://amitkazmirsky.com/2013/01/03/installing-rails-with-mysql-on-windows-8
actually thereis a problem with sertificates that has a different solutions, try this:

Fix SSL issues

“OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed”

1. Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem to “C:\RailsInstaller\”
2. Press WindowsKey+’x’ then ‘y’ (system), choose “Advanced system settings” to the left.
3. You are in the advance tab. Press “Environment Variables” button on the bottom.
4. In the “System Variables” section, add a new variable name “SSL_CERT_FILE”, value “C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem”

Comment: I haven't used railsinstaller, but I have used the windows installers for ruby and I've got a Ruby200 folder. Should I just place place it there? Edit: It worked, thank you so much!